# qualifying for AAdvantage elite status

Tags: loyalty-programs, american-airlines

According to [AAdvantage elite status](https://www.aa.com/i18n/aadvantage-program/elite-status/aadvantage-elite-status.jsp#elitequalification%E2%80%8B) here are the pre requisites for getting into each of the various elite statuses for American Airlines:

[image]

Do you need to have 25,000 EQMs **-and-** 30 EQSs **-and-** $3,000 EQDs or is any one of those sufficient to get you membership?

Also, let's say I bought a ticket for myself and my significant other for $1,500 each. Would my AAdvantage account get EQD credit for both purchases or just for the purchase of my ticket? Would it make a difference if my significant other had an AAdvantage number? I just ask about that because I note that purchases made for other people show up in the "My trips / Check-in" tab on the main page until I had the AAdvantage account for those other people.

Comment: https://www.aa.com/i18n/aadvantage-program/aadvantage-program-updates.jsp says: "To qualify for elite status, you need to meet thresholds for Elite Qualifying Dollars (EQDs) plus Elite Qualifying Miles (EQMs) or Elite Qualifying Segments (EQSs)" but it is still ambiguous whether it is `EQD and (EQM or EQS)` or `(EQD and EQM) or EQS`.

Comment: As to the second question, it's almost certainly only tickets for which you yourself are the passenger.  Your SO can earn the EQD for his/her own ticket.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to fulfill two of the requirements, either EQD + EQM or EQD + EQS.  Basically spend enough money and actually fly enough.  It seems to be designed to discourage frequent travelers from buying the cheapest tickets.

Something that some airlines have that they don't publicize much, if you live overseas outside their primary market, they waive the spending requirement and you only have to fulfill the miles or segments.  But you would have to check with AA to see if they offer this (assuming you don't live in the USA).

The points you earn in each category apply only to the passenger who is flying, even though you spent the money.  But you can earn dollar and/or miles via credit card expenditures as well, so you maybe able to benefit from your SO's tickets that way.

Your SO should have an AA account as well, simply to keep the miles their flights earn, even if they can't reach elite levels.

Comment: +1. It's worth noting that American will [give you 3000 EQDs](https://thepointsguy.com/2017/04/credit-card-spend-toward-aa-eqds/) if you can manage to spend $25K on some (but not all) of their branded credit cards in a calendar year, though that's a less generous policy than other airlines.